# NSTextField duplicates input

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield

I am building an installer plugin in obj-c which takes certain input values in `NSTextFields`, and does an action with `controlTextDidChange` which works perfectly fine in the installer on my machine (Sierra).

If I copy the installer to another machine (El Capitan), everytime I type in 'e' (or whatever) into the NSTextField, it automatically enters another 'e' after, so I have 2 duplicate chars (and `controlTextDidChange` runs 2x). Backspaces only erases one.

Why is this behaviour happening?

Edit: this is my `controlTextDidChange`

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj{
    NSTextField *textField = [obj object];

    /*portField triggered, only allow non empty numeric input*/
    if (textField == _portField){
        NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [textField.stringValue length]; i++) {
            unichar c = [textField.stringValue characterAtIndex:i];
            /*found none numeric, show last valid and do not proceed to write*/
            if (![charSet characterIsMember:c]) {
                if (i==0){
                    _portField.stringValue = @"";
                } else {
                    _portField.stringValue = lastValidPort.stringValue;
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //[self alert:@"call" :@"text change"];

    [self toggleContinueButton];

    NSNumber *portValue = [self stringToInt:_portField.stringValue];
    lastValidPort = portValue;

    NSDictionary *update = [self newValuesInDict];

    [self writeToCsv:update];
}
```

I have 2 `NSTextFields` calling this, and both of them show the same behaviour.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see how often it hits `controlTextDidChange` and where it is being called from?

Comment: … *and where it is being called from* is very important.

Comment: @Krumelur I cant use a debugger because xcode builds this into a bundle which i use in 'Packages'. I run by launching the pkg